# How many items can send in one amazon request?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I try to get [ASIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number) for movies in my DB, try to match via [EAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29). I created simple java class to connect with Amazon:

```
AWSECommerceServiceservice = new AWSECommerceService();
service.setHandlerResolver(new AwsHandlerResolver(AMAZON_SECRET_KEY));
AWSECommerceServicePortType port = service.getAWSECommerceServicePortDE();
Holder<OperationRequest> operationrequest = new Holder<OperationRequest>();
failedItem = 0;
doneItem = 0;

ItemLookup lookup = new ItemLookup();
lookup.setAWSAccessKeyId(AMAZON_ACCESS_ID);
lookup.setAssociateTag(ASSOCIATE_TAG);
ItemLookupRequest request = new ItemLookupRequest();
request.getResponseGroup().add("ItemAttributes");
request.setSearchIndex("Video");

request.setIdType("EAN");
//Here iterates on my amazon-movies object
   for (AmazonSIdN i : amazonItems) {
        request.getItemId().add(i.getEan());
         if (request.getItemId().size() % 10 == 0) { //numbers of items in request
             LOG.info("Request size = " + request.getItemId().size());
              break;
           }
    }
Holder<List<Items>> items = new Holder<List<Items>>();
lookup.getRequest().add(request);

port.itemLookup(lookup.getMarketplaceDomain(), lookup.getAWSAccessKeyId(), 
lookup.getAssociateTag(),lookup.getXMLEscaping(), lookup.getValidate(),  
lookup.getShared(), lookup.getRequest(),operationrequest, items);

        List<Items> result = items.value;
        for (int k = 0; k < result.get(0).getItem().size(); ++k) {
            Item i = result.get(0).getItem().get(k);
            //do something with item

        }
```

It is working, but one thing is really strange for me. When in this line:

```
if (request.getItemId().size() % 10 == 0) { //numbers of items in request
```

I use 40 000 instead of 10 WS returns:

```
The server sent HTTP status code 413: Request Entity Too Large
```

And this is understandable. But when I put number greater then 10 WS doesn't return eny errors but result has no items:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what I a'm doing wrong or what did I forget set? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, so I put it here maybe someone save some time in future.
In Amazon [ItemLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) documentatnion is written:

ItemId - One or more **(up to ten)** positive integers that uniquely identify an item. The meaning of the number is specified by IdType. That is, if IdType is ASIN, the ItemId value is an ASIN. If ItemIdis an ASIN, a search index cannot be specified in the request.

Type: String

Default: None

Constraints: Must be a valid item ID. For more than one ID, use a comma-separated list of up to ten IDs.